# Citrix IE detection

Tags: citrix

We have a website, which many users are accessing through Citrix. Certain things (namely video) drag down the Citrix server so much that I don't even want to try launching a video if the user is connecting from that.

Is there some way (on the web server end) of detecting if the browser that's connecting is being hosted by citrix? Everyone will be using IE 7 or 8 if that is relevant. I did a dump of all the request parameters and scanned through window.* and window.navigator.* in the browser but didn't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Have you contemplated using Citrix redirection so that instead of using your server to view  websites, the client uses it's own internet browser to do so?

> **Server to Client content redirection**; this makes it possible to start URLs locally on the client PC. Embedded URLs are intercepted on the server running Presentation Server and sent to the client. The user’s locally installed browser is used to display the website.

http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/terminal-services/general/client-server-content-redirection-explained.html

Comment: Yes, good to know I'm on the right track :-). The issue is that, if the client doesn't have content redirection on, I don't want to show them the video. So my goal is to detect whether they're using content redirection.